# Offline transaction time

Tags: ico

Hi there I made a transaction offline then published transaction for a ico. My full deposit is still showing in my wallet. Should the wallet show less the transaction?, Or does it have to be on the block before showing less transaction ammount in my wallet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wallet needs to be synced with the network to show the correct balance.